# How can i simplify this odd numbers code?

Tags: java, xcode, for-loop, if-statement

Is there a way to simplify this code of a program that print the odd numbers between 2 numbers that the user inputs, idk, maybe in the declaration of the for. I mean, do the same, but without the if, only the for?

```
int n1,n2;
System.out.println("Enter first number");
n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter second number");
n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
for (int i=n1; i < n2; i++)
{
    if( i % 2 != 0)
    {
        System.out.println(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: In terms of speed the modulo operator **%** should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Start with an odd `n1` (before the loop) and add 2 on every iteration. Like,

```
if (n1 % 2 == 0) {
    n1++;
}
for (int i = n1; i < n2; i += 2) {
    System.out.println(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: yes, it will work, but i mean that the program does the same, but without an if. Thanks for answering! Hope you can help me.

Comment: @AlbertoTeixidó This runs the `if` once, instead of on every iteration of the loop. The only way to avoid it is if you can mandate the user will only enter odd numbers for `n1`.

Comment: Or you can use Streams with filter, to not display if but that will internally use if.

Answer (score 1):

Without if statement this should work:

```
n1 += 1 - (n1 % 2); // (add 1 if n1 is even number, else 0)

for (int i = n1; i < n2; i += 2) {
    System.out.println(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: Also `n1 = n1 / 2 * 2 + 1` would work is OP does not like modulos

Answer (score 0):

*You could use a lambda expression*

```
IntStream.range( n1, n2 ).filter( n -> (n & 1) != 0 ).forEach( odd -> System.err.println( odd ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8+, you can use replace your for loop with `IntStream`. But it will just improve your code presentation but will internally use if (from direct visual it will remove if):

```
IntStream.range(n1, n2).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).forEach(i -> {
      System.out.println(i + " ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = (n1 % 2) == 0 ? n1 : n1+1 ; i < n2; i += 2) {
    System.out.println(i + " ");
}
```